# When running flutter build ios, I get the following error. I have already tried to uninstall and reinstall cocoapods but that does not work

Tags: ios, ruby, flutter, dependencies, cocoapods

I get the following error when running flutter build ios

```
Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_1_6_1.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
    [!] CDN: trunk Repo update failed - 80 error(s):
    undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass
    undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass
    undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass
    undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass
    undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass
    undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass
```

this continues on for a while and ends with `error running pod install.`

Comment: Did you try to install the pods from the mac terminal and not from the android studio terminal, because sometimes the android studio could not give us the proper results to the code related with the iOS.